# CMake Error after installing Flutter audiplayers package on Linux

Tags: flutter

I'm building a Flutter app and I'm currently developing on Linux, for Linux. I would like to play audio in my app, so I tried installing the audioplayers package.

I ran:

`flutter pub add audioplayers`

I then try running my app in debug mode (which worked before) and I get this error in the debug console:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
CMake Error at /snap/flutter/141/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:463 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /snap/flutter/141/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:643 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/audioplayers_linux/linux/CMakeLists.txt:24 (pkg_check_modules)
  
Exception: Unable to generate build files

Exited (1)
```

According to my git diff, the `flutter pub add audioplayers` command makes the following changes:

1. The `pubspec.yaml` file gets this dependency:

```
     audioplayers: ^5.2.1
```

2. The `pubspec.lock` file gets a bunch more dependencies
3. The `generated_plugin_registrant.cc` file (for Linux) gets these changes (and the Windows version gets similar changes):
   [image]
4. The `generated_plugins.cmake` file gets this change (for Linux, and a similar change for windows):

```
list(APPEND FLUTTER_PLUGIN_LIST
  audioplayers_linux
)
```

5. The `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.swift` file gets these changes:
   [image]

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors